# compare two dates in dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a column where I store dates as `dd/mm/yyyy`. Then I ask user to input in a form a new date (always as dd/mm/yyyy). I want to compare the input date to the last date that is in the excel already.

```
If Format(data_mov, "Short Date") < Format(data_last, "Short Date") Then
```

is not the way to go since it will compare two strings and the test will fail since 03/10/2018 looks smaller than 23/09/2018.

What is the correct way to test them? Something like converting them into timestamps and then compare (but is there something like the unixtimestamp in excel?)

Comment: Can't you just compare `date_mov` with `data_last`? **If you have to format them**.. instead of formatting to short date, why not format to YYYYMMDD? This makes date comparison work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You convert the strings to date and compare them:

```
' dd/mm/yyyy
' 1234567890

Dim Date1: Date1 = DateSerial(Mid(data_mov, 7, 4), Mid(data_mov, 4, 2), Mid(data_mov, 1, 2))
Dim Date2: Date2 = DateSerial(Mid(data_last, 7, 4), Mid(data_last, 4, 2), Mid(data_last, 1, 2))

If Date1 < Date2 Then
    ' ...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

> "What is the correct way to test them?"

IMHO, there is more than one way.

`if()` with `value()` will be straightforward.

`if()` with `year()`,`month()`,`day()`, `hour()`.. is another.

> "Something like converting them into timestamps and then compare (but
>   is there something like the unixtimestamp in excel?)"

The easiest (for me) is using `value()` function . Then build the desired `if()` statement on it.

Hope it helps. (:

---

Microsoft Excel for Windows uses the 1900 date system, by default. Which means the first date is January 1, 1900. a [Date](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349) and [Time](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/time-function-9a5aff99-8f7d-4611-845e-747d0b8d5457) function can be used to manipulate the year/date and time/hour/minutes values. The date/time in Excel is stored as a number. Where the decimal part range from 0.0 to 0.99988426 represent 0:00:00 (12:00:00 AM) to 23:59:59 (11:59:59 P.M.), and the integer part range from 0 to 9999 represent year 1900 to year 9999.